# Component isn't updating from computed value

Tags: vuejs3, vue-composition-api, vue-script-setup

I have a generic component linked to a computed value to simulate routing.
There is a current page property, and three links, whenever the user clicks on a link, that property gets updated via the renderPage.

Before switching to `<script setup>` the code worked fine, now, the generic component doesn't seem to do anything.

Here's the code:

```js
<script setup>
import { computed, ref } from "vue";
import HomePage from "./components/HomePage.vue";
import LoginPage from "./components/LoginPage.vue";
import UsersPage from "./components/UsersPage.vue";


const currentPage = ref("Home");

const renderPage = computed(() => `${currentPage.value}Page`)


function showHomePage() {
  currentPage.value = "Home";
}
function showLoginPage() {
  currentPage.value = "Login";
}
function showUsersPage() {
  currentPage.value = 'Users';
}
</script>

<template>
  <header class="header">
    <span class="logo">
      <img src="@/assets/vue-heart.png" width="30" />C'est La Vue
    </span>
    <nav class="nav">
      <a href="#" @click.prevent="showHomePage">Home</a>
      <a href="#" @click.prevent="showUsersPage">Users</a>
      <a href="#" @click.prevent="showLoginPage">Login</a>
    </nav>
  </header>
  <component :is="renderPage" />
</template>
```

The generic component is able to render the components properly if set manually, but whenever linked to the `renderPage` computed property, it doesn't work anymore.

The `renderPage` when added inside a mustache works as expected, updating the string as it should.

Comment: Thank you @tao, it does indeed answer my question but raises a few others. For example, why components need to be registered?

Comment: Because Vue needs a component definition in order to render that component. If the component is registered, Vue can map the string to the definition. If not, you need to pass the component definition to `is`. From [docs](https://vuejs.org/api/built-in-special-elements#component): *"When `is` is a string, it could be either an HTML tag name or a component's registered name."*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`import HomePage from "./components/HomePage.vue";` make a variable `HomePage`, not something in the the template context named `HomePage`. To refer to an imported component by name, make an object containing components by name:

```
const components = {HomePage, LoginPage, UserPage};
```

Then use it in the template:

```
  <component :is="components[renderPage]" />
```

But better is to reference the components directly:

```
<script setup>
import { computed, ref } from "vue";
import HomePage from "./components/HomePage.vue";
import LoginPage from "./components/LoginPage.vue";
import UsersPage from "./components/UsersPage.vue";


const renderPage = ref(HomePage);


</script>

<template>
  <header class="header">
    <span class="logo">
      <img src="@/assets/vue-heart.png" width="30" />C'est La Vue
    </span>
    <nav class="nav">
      <a href="#" @click.prevent="renderPage = HomePage">Home</a>
      <a href="#" @click.prevent="renderPage = UserPage">Users</a>
      <a href="#" @click.prevent="renderPage = LoginPage">Login</a>
    </nav>
  </header>
  <component :is="renderPage" />
</template>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, this indeed works. I guess my question is more about: why doesn't the component take into effect the computed property `renderPage` when it obviously returns the appropriate string for the generic component to load the appropriate page component.

Comment: @dhiaagr a string value like ” HomePage" isnt a variable HomePage. They are completely different things